# How to scroll down full page if page having 'Loading' at down of page using puppeteer

Tags: node.js

I need to get a full-page response of the site https://www.pluginauto.com/pre-owned-cars using puppeteer as the site having Loading at the bottom of the listings. What would be the proper cssSelector for loading button here?. How would it be implemented?

Help would be appreciated!